# Accengage: Custom notification sound

Tags: android, push-notification

As change log [3.3.0](http://docs.accengage.com/display/AND/Changelog) Accengage now allows programmer customizes notification sound.

> Static Lists : Add/Remove and get subscription status for lists of
>   users In-App/Alarm : Global Capping between distinct messages
>   In-App/Alarm : Global Delay between distinct messages Push : Custom
>   notification sound

But as I research, I cannot find where can I custom this. Please tell me how to do on android.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a specific sound to be played for your notification , try the following 
Create a notification object by calling a notification service and passing relevant arguments to it .
Now on this notification object you have to call 
mynotification.sound which should refer to the MP3 file you want to be played for the notification .
This MP3 file should be in raw folder .

See if it works

Answer (score 0):

Set notification ring tone like this,

```
Uri notification1 = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification1);
r.play();
```